# jQuery UI Datepicker hash href misinterpreted by AngularJs Routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

### **This is actually my own fault. I did not properly initialize the model for the datepicker. When the datepicker is properly initialized, jQuery UI prevents the navigation event from firing. If you're experiencing this problem as well, then like me, you're doing something else wrong. I will leave this here as a cautionary tale.**

---

### Background:

I am trying to use the jQuery UI datepicker plugin within an AngularJs application.

It is a single page app that uses Angular's client side routing (**this is a critical detail**).

I am using jQuery UI v1.8.24 and AngularJs v1.2.2

### The Problem:

In order to select a date, you must click a day in the calendar. Each day in the calendar is basically a stylized anchor tag with a href attribute, set to a hash tag. For example, the HTML for day 17 in the calendar looks something like this

```
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a>
```

When the user clicks this date, **Angular will think they are trying to follow a link to the page that is found at the route "#/" and dutifully try to retrieve that page with AJAX.** If it exists, it will show it. If it doesn't, the user get's a nice blank page. Obviously, neither is what I want. I want Angular to do nothing but update the model when the user clicks a date.

### Attempted Solutions:

**I have tried using HTML5 routing (the one that doesn't use hash tags), but that doesn't help**: instead of trying to find a different page, Angular simply reloads the view you are currently on, clobbering any changes the user may have made.

I have also tried editing the source code for the jQuery UI datepicker so that it doesn't use a hash tag in the href. That works from an Angular perspective, but it breaks the datepicker. Without the hashtag, the UI for the datepicker doesn't update properly. Also, I would like to find a solution that doesn't involve altering the source code for jQuery UI, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried using non-html5 mode `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');`  this will set up `#!/[route]` routing.

Comment: How about capturing click events from datepicker and stopping propagation/preventing default action?

Comment: Also there is an Angular-UI-Date directive for jQuery-UI's date picker: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

Comment: Actually, this has all been my own fault. I did not properly initialize the model for the datepicker. It was undefined, which was causing an exception to be thrown. Apparently, when everything is set up properly, this is not an issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can you provide more details on how to "initialize the model"?

Answer (score 2):

May be this has already crossed your mind. But ideally **you should use the directives in [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)**. One reason [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) exist is to provide Angular directives (essentially angular wrappers) for commonly used jQuery plugins.

In Angular UI Bootstrap getting started section it mentions about the bootstrap's use of # tags causing problems in Angular, and the same problem exists with jQueryUI plugins.

> Original Bootstrap's CSS depends on empty href attributes to style
>   cursors for several components (pagination, tabs etc.). But in
>   AngularJS adding empty href attributes to link tags will cause
>   unwanted route changes. This is why we need to remove empty href
>   attributes from directive templates and as a result styling is not
>   applied correctly.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually using Angular UI Bootstrap for a number of things in my application. However, I found their date picker unsatisfactory for my purposes. I built a custom angular directive that wraps the date picker found here: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ (which is an extension of the stock jQuery date picker). I didn't mention this in my description because I thought it was an unnecessary detail.

Comment: It's interesting that the people who built Angular UI ran into the same problem though. The reason I had my problem was because I was passing the date picker an unitialized date. Maybe the timepicker extension I'm using does more than I thought? Or maybe they ran into this problem with an older version of jQuery UI than what I'm using? I'd have to dig through the source code of jQuery UI to know for sure, which I'm not inclined to do at the moment. If someone else knows and wants to share, I would be grateful.